# How to skip test created using tdd interface in inter 4?

Tags: typescript, async-await, intern

How can i skip the test created using `tdd` interface in intern 4. I tried using `this.skip('message')`  the value of `this` is `null` so i don't have access to `skip()` function to this .

Below is the structure of test.

```
  test('test 1', async ({remote}) => {
    const PAGE_TITLE = 'Projections'
    projectionTab = await viewEventPage.clickOnTab<ProjectionTab>(ProjectionTab);
    await projectionTab.waitTillPageIsFullyLoaded();
    const tabTitle: string = await projectionTab.getPageTitle();
    assert.include(tabTitle, PAGE_TITLE, 'Projection page did not load');
    const checkBtnEnable: boolean = await remote.findByXpath('//*[@id="addCommunication"]').isEnabled();
    assert.equal(checkBtnEnable, true, 'Add Projection Button is disabled');
});
```

So now what i actually want to know is i get reference to test object form inside the `async function` in above test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destructuring the test instance directly, get the complete instance and then extract the driver object from it if you still want.

```
test('test 1', async funtion() {
  // Extract the driver here or you can just use this.driver wherever
  const { driver } = this;
  ...
  this.skip() // Now this should work
  ...
});
```

Comment: I already tried that way but still getting same "TypeError: Cannot read property 'skip' of null" error

Comment: Could you replace `{remote, skip}` with just `test` and check what properties the `test` object has?

Comment: it shows the transpiled version of steps inside test. and when i use skip() only it says cannot set property skipped of undefined.

Comment: I've made an update and I believe this should work. Could you check?

Comment: Still getting error :       error TS2345: Argument of type '() => { setup: (this: Test) => Promise<void>; .....      cannot post whole error here..

Comment: That error seems weird. I've updated the answer with an alternate. Could you try that? Also, could you share the complete snippet that you are trying for which you got that error and probably the complete error too? You could share it using https://pastebin.com/ since its too long to paste here.

Answer (score 0):

The test function is passed the test object (which is where you're getting `remote` from in the original example). You can call `skip` on that.

```
test('test 1', async testObj => {
  if (condition1) {
    testObj.skip();
  } else {
    const { remote } = testObj;
    await remote.get('...');
    ...
  }
});
```